# How to copy paste without source font lock in emacs?

Tags: emacs, colors, elisp

When you copy text from one buffer to another (M-w and C-y) it copy text with font-lock and when you paste it it display with colors from the buffer I copied the text. Is it possible to change that to make it display with font from new buffer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the doc for user options `yank-excluded-properties` and `yank-handled-properties`.  And start with the doc for `yank`: `C-h f yank`.  It tells you:

```
When this command inserts text into the buffer, it honors the
`yank-handled-properties' and `yank-excluded-properties'
variables, and the `yank-handler' text property.  See
`insert-for-yank-1' for details.
```

IOW, just tell `yank` not to paste properties such as `face` and `font-lock-face`.

See also the Elisp manual, node `Yanking`.

Comment: I've added `(add-to-list 'yank-excluded-properties 'font)` and `(add-to-list 'yank-excluded-properties 'font-lock-face)` but when I yank to  Fundamental mode from some source code I still have colors.

Comment: Also I don't have docs for `yank-handled-properties` in Emacs 24.2

Answer (score 2):

I found `(set-text-properties (point) (mark) nil)` delete color of selected region.

I also want to remove read-only properties. But I don't know how to do it.(Sorry it is my question.)

Answer (score -1):

With this in your setup:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-r") (lambda()(interactive)(revert-buffer nil t)))
```

you'll need to do <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> <kbd>C-x C-r</kbd>.

Comment: I think you put that in wrong question. I've ask about font-lock.

Comment: It's the proper answer. Did you try it?

Comment: What if I don't want to save the file. It revert the file to previous state. All my changes that I didn't save will go away.

Comment: That's why you save and revert. I've never seen having to save a problem. You can play around with `font-lock-fontify-buffer`, maybe that's what you want.

Comment: In GNU Emacs 24.3.1, reverting a buffer does not remove the font locking—or, at least, it does not restore the text color to the default.